# How to display month name in multi-datepicker plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to displaying multiple date picker range format like(Mar 2, 2015 - Mar 12, 2016) used one plugin http://multidatespickr.sourceforge.net/ and I tried following code

```
$(function() {
   $(".datepicker").multiDatesPicker({
        minDate: 0, 
        showButtonPanel: true, 
        changeMonth: true, 
        changeYear: true, 
        onSelect: function(dateText, inst) { 
                     inst.settings.defaultDate = dateText; 
                  }
    });
});
```

but it is not working, someone help me?

Comment: Where do you want to show month?

Comment: in input box format like(Mar 2, 2015 - Mar 12, 2016)

Answer (score 0):

You may not need `onSelect` handler. It is easily possible to do with following setting:

```
dateFormat: "M d, yy",
separator:' - '
```

```js
    $(function() {
      $("#dp").multiDatesPicker({
        dateFormat: 'M d, yy',separator:' - '
      });
    });
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://multidatespickr.sourceforge.net/jquery-ui.multidatespicker.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://multidatespickr.sourceforge.net/css/pepper-ginder-custom.css" />

<input id="dp" type="text" />
```

Comment: i got 30% result, here when i select more then two date are visible more then two dates in input box, but i need  date-piker range like Mar 2, 2015 - Mar 12, 2016

Comment: datepicker range form like Mar 2, 2015 - Mar 12, 2016 need input box

Comment: well it would make it 50% not 30. hopefully it is 100% now.

Comment: i tried  $(function() {
  $(".datepicker").multiDatesPicker({
    dateFormat: 'M d, yy',
 minDate: 2
  });and also range formate (-) is not coming how?please help me
});

Comment: read the answer again, check new config property `separator: ' - '`. The code given in answer is working. click on **Run code snippet** button to see it in action.

Comment: date selection working but date picker range format like(Mar 2, 2015 - Mar 12, 2016) not work?please help

Comment: yes readed and i run the snippet , snippet also show multiple date but not range Mar 2, 2015 - Mar 12, 2016